# Highstock charts - Show the blank space up to the current date

Tags: charts, highcharts, points

Currently, I'm having trouble to force the highstock chart to display a blank space up to the current date. It focuses the data I give it.

What I have is:

[image]

What I want is something like this

[image]

As you can see I want the data to stop at the date of the latest data point and then the graph should show a blank space and stop at the current date. Obv there is not data points for those times

Answer (score 0):

You can control how empty points, and missing points are shown by looking at:

[xAxis.ordinal](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal)

> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart regardless of the actual time or x distance between them. This means that missing data periods (e.g. nights or weekends for a stock chart) will not take up space in the chart. Having ordinal: false will show any gaps created by the gapSize setting proportionate to their duration.

[xAxis.max](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.max)

> The maximum value of the axis. If null, the max value is automatically calculated.

[plotOptions.series.connectNulls](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.connectNulls)

> Whether to connect a graph line across null points, or render a gap between the two points on either side of the null.

Which means that for your graph, you will want to set:

```
xAxis: {
  ordinal: false,
  max: (new Date()).getTime() //to set the current date and time as a maximum
}
```